# create dynamic objects using spring boot hashmap

Tags: java, spring, hashmap

i wrote the below code to form custom objects. but its returning only single object. like below

**{"fathername":null,"name":"ks"}**

but i want like below(array object)

**[{"name":"test","fathername":"test123"},{"name":"ks","fathername":null}]**

but it is returning single object. what i am missing here, please pour your suggestions

```
public HashMap<String, String> applicantlistv2() {      
    List<Applicant> users = repository.findAll();
    
    HashMap<String, String> myhash = new HashMap<String, String>();
   
    
    for (Applicant applicant : users) {
        myhash.put("fathername", applicant.getFather_name());
        myhash.put("name", applicant.getFirst_name());
        
        System.out.println(applicant.getFirst_name());

    }

 //return repository.findAll();
    return myhash;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each iteration you are replacing the same key. So only the data in the last iteration would be available.

Replace the code as follows:

```
List<Map<String, String>> myhash = new ArrayList<>();       
for (Applicant applicant : users) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("fathername", applicant.getFather_name());
    map.put("name", applicant.getFirst_name());
    myhash.add(map);
    System.out.println(applicant.getFirst_name());
}

return myhash;
```

Comment: but I have one clarification, Map is only accepting string datatype values, how can I use different data types in a same hash? @gautam m

Comment: @KalaiSelvan currently your map is `Map<String, String>`, if the value part could be of different types then use `Map<String, Object>`